# Replace onmouseover/hover event

Tags: jquery, hover, prestashop, onmouseover

im not a programmer and want to ask a question how to replace onmouseover/hover event
on that script

```
 $('#category, #manufacturer, #prices-drop, #best-sales, #new-products').mouseover(function(){
    $('#product_list .product_img_link').each(function(){
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kisweb/w5UUk/1/

This is releated with Prestashop module that shows product active parameters on product list category view. http://bit.ly/N3qduS (hover on the ipod and You will see)

The main problem is that before purchase script maker says that he can help with module customize but after this he cant help me... ;/

I need to show this attributes below the describtion and without need of hover something. I suspect that will be hard because (im not sure) database is asked for product attribs on hover event....

Comment: what do you have in your fiddle? just js code.....

Comment: @Jai yes its just js because this is a part of the module responsible for show parameters at .product_img_link class when mouse is over image.
Wolff. I want only to view products attribs without any hover event. I want to show customer available product attribs at prestashop category view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add as CSS rule:

```
.product_img_link .speAttr { display: block !important; }
```

Comment: And maybe some hint how to move it from the image to below describtion?

Comment: You should ask a new question regarding this.

Comment: I will play and maybe i will be able to solve this one :)
Thanks Wolff!